# I gave her books/Her books were given by me

Tags: passive-voice

One of the English professors working in an Engineering college announced 20 years that he invented the "Rare third passive usage" and all the English News papers in India published the news widely. His example is:

- Active Voice: I gave her books.
- Passive Voice

  1. She was given books by me.
  2. Books were given to her by me.
  3. Her books were given by me.

The trick works if the indirect object is feminine gender and the direct object is plural. For example, we can't say" him books were given by me or them books were given by me. Similarly, "I gave her a book" can't be passivized as "her a book was given by me. I was only talking about the rare third passive Usage but not about the well known two passive usages.

I asked my English professor whether he would agree that it was an invention. He reputed it, saying that the professor who feels that he made an invention should have sent it to the best Institutes like English and Foreign Language Universities in which he was working.

Is this an invention or not?

Comment: What changes if the indirect object is male? "Books were given to him by me"

Comment: *I gave her books* would almost always mean *I gave [some] books **to her***. Pragmatically, it's very unlikely you'd use just those 4 words to mean that you gave ***her** books = books that **belonged** to her* to some unspecified recipient, but syntactically speaking those 4 words *could* carry that sense. From which it follows that your *Her books were given by me* is an incredibly unlikely utterance. Just forget all about it.

Comment: You claim `The trick works if the indirect object is feminine gender and the direct object is plural.` Why does the gender matter? Why doesn't replacing "her" with ""him" work? If you have miswrote, you can edit and clarify.

Comment: I gave her books (Active)

Comment: @Mari-LouA The feminine possessive adjective *her* (her book) is the same as the object pronoun *her* (I gave it to her). That's not so with the masculine gender - the possessive adjective is *his* (his book) but the object pronoun is *him* (I gave it to him). The masculine possessive adjective cannot possibly be parsed as an object pronoun, it's a different word.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie   Oh, I see. The object pronoun (her) is the same as the possessive pronoun (her).  **Her name was given by her** (her mother)

Comment: In (3), _her_ can only be the possessive (her books).

Comment: @Jvlnarasimharao: I don't know what you mean be "an invention", but you seem to understand the syntactic issues here perfectly well, so I don't know exactly what you're asking. If you just want us to confirm that your ridiculously contrived examples are "syntactically valid", then I don't see the point, since in practice no native speaker would ever say anything like *Her books were given by me* in normal circumstances.

Comment: You always tumble when you answer somebody's question. They are not my examples but they are given by the professor who said that the rare third passage was his invention and the newspapers published it.

Comment: You always tumble when you answer somebody's question. They are not my examples but they are given by the professor who said that the rare third passage was his invention and the newspapers published it. I just want to know how far his claim was correct. If the sentences are ridiculous, they are not mine but they are professor's. Though you are a great Scholar, you need to be somewhat polite in the use of your language. I don't care even if I am suspended from the site for some time or forever

Comment: In the phrase "her books", that definitely does not mean the object pronoun "her". It's the possessive. Which means there is an equivalent for male pronouns: "his books". It's just as valid to say "her books were given by me" as it is to say "his books were given by me" (though both are awkward). Insisting on equivocating the "her" here with the object pronoun of the same form to make it "more rare" would, indeed, make the entire syntax invalid in the English language. So it's a contrived and equivocated structure, not an "invention".

Comment: In British English we call this "a load of old rubbish".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "invent" grammar, or at least, if you do, its not something that would get reported in newspapers. So this part of the tale is utter nonsense.  I suspect it is some form of joke that your Professor is playing on you.

Let's look at your example, in the active voice:

> I gave her books.

There is actually a syntactic ambiguity here.  This is most likely to be understood as SVOO with "her" being the indirect object, and two noun phrases "her" and "books". But it could be SVO with "her" being a determinative, "her books" being a single noun phrase.  In this parsing, there is an unexpressed indirect object, the "to someone" is omitted.  While this is syntactically possible it is unrealistic, in almost every context.

This ambiguity only exists because the object pronoun "her" is the same in form as the determinative.  If we change to masculine pronouns the ambiguity goes.  "I gave him books" is SVOO and "I gave his books" is SVO

So there's no "trick" here.  The first sentence is the passive form. The second is the passive form of "I gave books to her", which has the same meaning. The third is the passive form of the SVO parsing.  In the passive voice, the ambiguity goes.  Your sentence 3 has a *different meaning* to 1 and 2.

There's nothing very clever about this.  Here's a similar "invention".

Active:  I cut the grass.

Passive 1.  The grass is cut by me.
Passive 2. The grass was cut by me.

This "trick" works because the verb "cut" has the same form in the past tense as in the present. It's similar to your example, because a syntactic ambiguity in the active form is not present in the passive.
But all this is Castles-in-the-sky grammar, and has no real application to English as a form of communication or persuasion.